# How to see the code that runs after a specific action?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

The `Pause script execution` button in Chrome DevTools is great for figuring out what does what... EXCEPT when there's code that's just constantly running so it gets paused before you can do what you want it to do. This is very annoying and I was wondering if there's a way to get around it. (Doesn't have to be Chrome)

Comment: is [debugger;](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/debugger) what you're after?

Comment: @Lucasjm Unfortunately not, because I want to do this with websites that aren't my own. However, I didn't know about that and I'm glad I now do!